# css text-overflow position in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am having an issue getting some text to align correctly in IE browsers when using the text-overflow ellipsis styling. When placing this styling on a span the following spans become out of line from the ellipsis, seeming to cause a break. [Example here](http://dabblet.com/gist/5404436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because you make the first `span` element display as `display:inline-block`.

Either display the rest of the spans with that as well – or set `vertical-align:text-bottom` for the first span.

Comment: I used the vertical-align and it worked wonderfully. Thanks for this tip!